# Can't send an id to the controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am sending an id to the delete controller, but it's "null". 
May I missing anything ?

This is the delete controller:

```
public function destroy(DomainPage $domainPage)
    {
        dd($domainPage);
    }
```

This is the model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'domain_page_slug',
        'is_published',
        'domain_page_discount',
    ];

    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DomainPagesTranslations::class, 'domain_page_id');
    }
```

And this is the blade:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.domain.destroy', [$domainPage->id])}}" method='post' class=" text-right" >
         <a href="{{route('admin.domain.edit', [$domainPage->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-sm">Edit</a>
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        @method('delete')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

This is the route:

```
Route::resource('domain', 'Admin\DomainPageController')
```

Comment: What do your routes look like, can you post them? Have you tried `{{route('admin.domain.destroy', [$domainPage])}}`?

Comment: it is a resource controller, there is not  bug in route

Comment: Show it :) the error lies there

Comment: controller work , for example I can dd(3)  but , an ID is null

Comment: I edit post and put route

Comment: remove edit from your form, place it outside and then just click delete button, and do you have a prefix for your resource route `admin` ?

Comment: no i do not have prefix ,  at first I tried without edit , but It doesn't work

Comment: then try this way `{{route('domain.destroy', $domainPage->id)}}` remove `admin`

Comment: again null :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try it:

```php
public function destroy(int $id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```